# How can I stop a line that tail has been killed being printed to the console?

Tags: bash

I have a script that tails a log file in the background and then redirects it to a file:

```
tail -f ~/dev/logs/*.log > $LOG 2>&1 &
LOG_PID=$!
```

Later on I kill it:

```
kill $LOG_PID
```

But it prints an untidy message to the console:

```
/Users/.../restart: line 47: 66634 Terminated: 15          tail -f ~/dev/logs/*.log > $LOG 2>&1s
```

How do I stop that message being printed?

Comment: Show an [MCVE] for your shell script, and explain *exactly* how is that script started. Do you use `trap`  in your shell script? Why do you write `2>&1s` instead of `2>&1` ? At last, explain how you get that untidy message, and why don't you want it (I find it *really* useful).

Comment: Ops. Typo in my question. Now corrected.

Answer (score 3):

You are redirecting both stdout and stderr into your log file (by redirecting stderr into stdout) - this is why you are seeing the `Terminated` message. Since the error is actually written to stderr, by only redirecting stdout, you won't see that error log line.

Basically all you need to do is remove the section where you are redirecting stderr into stdout (`2>&1`).

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this works:

```
kill -INT $LOG_PID
```